# How to handle/process Data payload (inc. Notification) of Firebase Cloud Messagingin an Android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question regarding receiving a Firebase message with both Notification and Data payload. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) says the Data will arrive "in the extras of the intent".

My question is **which Intent (or Activity)**? There will be a screen where the user left off when switching the app to the background. So, do I need to try to retrieve the Extra for all Intents/Activities in my app?

Where and how do I actually code to retrieve the Data payload once the app comes to the foreground?

Thanks!

ADDED:

I mean, I alraedy have 10+ Activities, and there will be more when the app is finished. So, do I have to retrieve the Extra for all Activities to see if the app has been re-opened with any Push data payload?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a description of how to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the document you linked in your question, it states:

> Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your **launcher Activity**

The launcher activity is specified in the manifest using category LAUNCHER. For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can override the default behavior to specify another activity.  In your [message notification data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), add property `click_action` with value of an action string.  Then create the activity and give it an intent filter in the manifest that matches the action.  For example, with message:

```
{
  "to": "dhVgCGVkTSR:APA91b...mWsm3t3tl814l",
  "notification": {
    "title": "New FCM Message",
    "body": "Hello World!",
    "click_action": "com.example.FCM_NOTIFICATION"
  },
  "data": {
    "score": "123"
  }
}
```

Define the intent filter like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyFcmNotificationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.FCM_NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And to clarify the documentation a bit, the data payload is not delivered to the activity when the message is received; it's delivered when the user clicks on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the `FirebaseMessagingService` class.

And override the `onMessageReceived` method.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
// ...

// TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
        // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
        scheduleJob();
    } else {
        // Handle message within 10 seconds
        handleNow();
    }

}

// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

// Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
// message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification 
 method below.
 }
```

Make sure you register the service in the manifest.

Comment: I have already done this. But the documentation says that if the payload contains both Data and Notification, it won't arrive in onMessageReceived but will be "in extras of the intent".